# Get opened input stream from rest template for large file processing

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I am looking for a way to get opened input stream from rest template - I was trying to used ResponseExtractor, but the stream is getting closed before returning, as written here:

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-7357

"Note that you cannot simply return the InputStream from the extractor, because by the time the execute method returns, the underlying connection and stream are already closed"

I hope that there is a way and I will not have to write to my output stream directly in the rest template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find a way to do it, the stream is always getting closed. As a workaround I created the following code:

```
public interface ResourceReader {
    void read(InputStream content);
}
```

with the following implementation:

```
public class StreamResourceReader implements ResourceReader {

private HttpServletResponse response;

public StreamResourceReader(HttpServletResponse response) {
    this.response = response;
}

@Override
public void read(InputStream content) {
    try {
        IOUtils.copy(content, response.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
}
}
```

then in controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "document/{objectId}")
public void getDocumentContent(@PathVariable String objectId, HttpServletResponse response) {
    ResourceReader reader = new StreamResourceReader(response);
    service.readDocumentContent(objectId, reader);
}
```

call to rest template:

```
restTemplate.execute(uri, HttpMethod.GET, null,
            new StreamResponseExtractor(reader));
```

and the string response extractor:

```
@Override
public ResponseEntity extractData(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
    reader.read(response.getBody());
    return null;
}
```

and it works like a charm! :)

Comment: so this does not load entire file into memory?

Comment: yes, it doesn't require having entire file in the memory. It will load the entire file while processing it, but not much memory is required

Comment: I followed same thing. but I am seeing inputStream getting truncated. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46332692/response-body-from-resttemplate-is-getting-truncated-when-downloading-a-file